# Comparing data frames with python pandas that have duplicate entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with python pandas data frames and have a problem comparing two data frames.

df columns:

A => string name 
B => timestamp 
C => timestamp 
D => int 
E => float

```python
cols = ['A','B','C','D','E']

df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, sep=',', header=None, names=cols, 
                     usecols=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
                     converters={'B':transform,'C':transform,'D':transform,'E':transform},
                     dtype={'B': np.float64},
                           {'C': np.float64},
                           {'D': np.float64},
                           {'E': np.float64})

df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, sep=',', header=None, names=cols, 
                         usecols=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
                         converters={'B':transform,'C':transform,'D':transform,'E':transform},
                     dtype={'B': np.float64},
                           {'C': np.float64},
                           {'D': np.float64},
                           {'E': np.float64})
```

where df1 is:

```python
   A    B           C          D     E 
0  g  08:15:32    08:12:12    100   11.5 
1  g  08:17:45    08:12:12    101   11.3 
2  g  08:25:22    08:12:12    102   11.4 
3  m  08:36:15    08:30:15    250   17.5 
4  m  08:45:14    08:30:15    250   17.6
```

and df2 is:

```python
    A     B      C        D     E
 0  g  08:15:15  08:12:12  105  11.5
 1  m  08:37:07  08:30:15  200  17.3
 2  m  08:38:13  08:30:15  250  17.6
 3  m  08:45:12  08:46:14  200  23.4
```

I want to compare both data frames where key is ['A','C'] for all matching rows and not drop any duplicates.  As I want to know which data frame might have extra records.  So my resulting data frame would be:

df12

```python
   A     B         C       D     E    df   difference  diff-D    diff-E

0  g   08:15:32  08:12:12  100  11.5  df1     Y        100-->105  NaN 
0  g   08:15:15  08:12:12  105  11.5  df2     Y        105-->100  NaN
1  g   08:17:45  08:12:12  101  11.3  df1
  NaN   NaN       NaN      NaN  NaN   df2    missing   NaN        NaN
2  g   08:25:22  08:12:12  102  11.4  df1
  NaN   NaN       NaN      NaN  NaN   df2    missing   NaN        NaN
3  m   08:36:15  08:30:15  250  17.5  df1      Y       250-->200  17.5-->17.3
1  m   08:37:07  08:30:15  200  17.3  df2      Y       200-->250  17.3-->17.5
4  m   08:45:14  08:30:15  250  17.6  df1      N
2  m   08:38:13  08:30:15  250  17.6  df2      N
  NaN   NaN       NaN      NaN  NaN   df1    missing   NaN        NaN
3  a   08:45:12  08:46:14  200  23.4  df2
```